# Dimension error when obtaining delta term in backward propagation (Neural network)

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm creating a image recognition neural network with three layers with these dimensions: 400 features, 40 nodes, 40 nodes, 10 targets (images of digits 0 to 9), therefore these are my weights (theta):

```
 theta1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.00001, high=0.0001, size=(40,401))
 theta2 = np.random.uniform(low=0.00001, high=0.0001, size=(40,41))
 theta3 = np.random.uniform(low=0.00001, high=0.0001, size=(10,41))
```

I am following Andrew Ng's [approach](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning.html). I am having some trouble getting back propagation to work.
First, I get the delta_4 term by finding the difference between the actual results and the predictions. Then, the remaining delta terms are obtained using the following equations,

[image]

where g' is the derivative of the sigmoid function.
I coded up the following function:

```
def get_delta(nodes_current, theta_current, delta_previous):
     derivative = np.multiply(nodes_current, 1-nodes_current)
     matmul_term = np.matmul(np.transpose(theta_current), delta_previous)
     delta_current = np.multiply(matmul_term, derivative)
     return delta_current
```

Then, the whole backpropagation process to obtain the gradients is the following:

```
def backward_prop3(y_vectors, a1, a2, a3, a4, theta1, theta2, theta3):
     #y_vectors is a 10 by m (num of training examples) matrix
     #a1 is the features
     #a2, a3 are the hidden nodes
     #a4 is the output

     m = y_vectors.shape[1]
 
     delta4 = a4 - y_vectors

     delta3 = get_delta(a3, theta3, delta4)
     triangle3 = np.matmul(delta4, np.transpose(a3))

     delta2 = get_delta(a2, theta2, delta3)
     triangle2 = np.matmul(delta3, np.transpose(a2))

     triangle1 = np.matmul(delta2[1:,:],np.transpose(a1))

     grad3 = (1/m)*triangle1
     grad2 = (1/m)*triangle2 
     grad1 = (1/m)*triangle1 

     return grad1, grad2, grad3
```

The problem occurs in the line to get delta2, specifically in the get_delta function line:

```
matmul_term = np.matmul(np.transpose(theta_current), delta_previous)
```

and the error says

```
matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 51 is different from 50)
```

I've checked the dimensions of my theta matrices and also reviewed the course notes, but I don't get why this doesn't work as I've implemented it exactly as shown in the equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have theta of size 41 while you have 40 features that causes the error. To debug this, please make sure that all matrices have valid dimensions so they can multiply with each other.

Your delta2 will have dimensions 41x41 and your theta2 has dimensions 40x41. Thus, transpose(theta2)*delta2 will try to multiply 41x40 * 41x41. This causes a dimension mismatch. Your theta2 should have dimensions 41x... for this to work.